# exec throws "no such file or directory" but folder exists and so does the file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, exec

I'm using the following `exec` command:

**MainFolder** is the main folder
inside it **mainScript.sh** and **settings** folder

**mainScript.sh** (Located in **MainFolder**) :

```
....
...
...
exec "../settings/helper.sh"
```

The file `helper.sh` is located one folder before the current directory , in `settings` folder
but `exec` throws `no such file or directory`.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: From where are you running `mainScript.sh`? In the directory it exists or somewhere else?

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: @Cyrus: `./mainScript.sh`

Comment: Do you change the directory somewhere in your script before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variable MAINFOLDER in your script mainScript.sh

```
MAINFOLDER=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
```

and call any script relative to `$MAINFOLDER`

if settings is in $MAINFOLDER

```
exec "${MAINFOLDER}/settings/helper.sh"
```

if settings is located one folder before

```
exec "${MAINFOLDER}/../settings/helper.sh"
```